# backslashes in perl substitution

Tags: perl, escaping, substitution

I'm trying my luck with a perl one-liner changing some commands in a bunch of .tex files. I got as far as the following:

```
perl -pi -e "s/\Q\linenum{some more stuff}\E/\Q\uln\E/g" *tex
```

Which results in `\lLn` instead of the expected replacement patter `\uln`. Apparently while `\Q` and `\E` take care of other special characters, they don't take care of the `\l` `\u` changing the case of the next character, how would I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\Q\E` works best for `\Q$var\E`. Elsewhere, you can use `\` to escape characters that need escaping.

```
perl -i -pe's/\\linenum\{some more stuff\}/\\uln/g' *tex
```